# How do you stop downloading the spam folder with a Gmail account?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, email-client

How do I force my email client ([eM Client](http://www.emclient.com/)) to stop downloading emails in the spam folder of my Gmail account?

Is there a way to permanently delete spam from the server before they get sent to my spam folder in my email client? If so, can I do this in Gmail's settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your email client is set up with IMAP, you can uncheck the "Show in IMAP" button on the [Gmail Label Settings Page](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labels), and it should stop.